# Hibernate throws ObjectNotFoundException even though the object exists in the database?

Tags: hibernate

I was having mysterious failures with Hibernate not finding objects, so I wrote a Unit Test which checks each row by first retrieving it statelessly, and then trying to grab the same object again into the session by ID.

The result is the code below. Why does the currentSession fail to find the object, when clearly the object exists in the DB? I need to get the object into the current session.

[image]

Comment: did you try hibernate [session.load](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable))?

Comment: Yes. load() returns null

Comment: can you check if item.getId() is returning a valid id?

Comment: Checked. It returns the correct ID value.

Comment: this is probably related to how you manage your transactions. Your current session is running in a different transaction that the one you use to save the entities. That's why currentSession is unaware of them. If you save the entity using the same session, I'm guessing you won't have this issue. Current session is managed by hibernate so I don't know if you can somehow manually commit its transaction and start a new one to find your entities.

Comment: When I use the same session, I get a different error. See my other SO question. I’ll post the link when I’m on a desktop pc.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the beginning of the question, this code was part of a Unit Test.

It turns out, the problem was caused by an earlier test in the test-suite: it was deleting the same object from the Session, but not flushing or clearing the session. As a result the object still existed in the database, but the delete was already pending inside of Hibernate.